# Steam update error on UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: steam

Steam always have this error on start even I updated it.

[image]

And also Steam not Launching the Dota 2 in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

Those two commands will solve your problem, open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and copy&paste (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste in terminal) them in:

```
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3{,.disable}
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1{,.disable}
```

As for your dota 2 problem try if those two lines fix it for you:

```
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1{,.disable}
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6{,.disable}
```

Comment: thanks for the steam it is working. for dota still not orking

Comment: do you have any error output you can add to your question for the dota 2 errors?

Comment: there is no error. after you press the play button for launch. It will just display on Steam GUI that it is running and if you go to system monitor it was there running but it never launch nor no icon displayed.